# How to check if process is already running by name in JXA

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

Using `/usr/bin/osascript` JS to automate my task, struggling with a check if process is already running or not:

```js
const app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

function run(args) {
  const query = args[0]
  let response = 'Wrong command passed'
  if (query === 'on') { // need to check if process named "asdf" is already running
    response = 'Process turned ON'
  } else if (query === 'off') { // need to check if process named "asdf" is already running
    response = 'Process turned OFF'
  }
  return response
}
```

JXA documentation could be better, i want to implement a check in an if construction. I've tried to make it using:

```js
const se = Application('System Events')
const process = se.processes.byName('processname')
```

But it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself:

```js
const PNAME = `ps aux | grep processname | grep -v grep | wc -l | xargs echo`
```

Getting `processname`, if it's running, it returns `1`, otherwise `0`. All what's left to do is:

```js
if (app.doShellScript(PNAME) < 1) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Solved myself:
>
> ```
> const PNAME = `ps aux | grep processname | grep -v grep | wc -l | xargs echo`
> ```
>
> Getting "processname", if it's running, it returns 1, otherwise 0.

Were I to call out to a shell to do this, I would aim to make it as an efficient combination of commands as possible.  `xargs`, `wc`, and the second pipe into `grep` are all unnecessary: if `grep processname` matches, the exit status of the command will be `0`, and in all other cases, non-zero.  It looks like the only reason you pipe through to those other programs is because you didn't utilise the most effective set of program options when calling `ps`:

```
const PNAME = 'ps -Acxo comm | grep processname > /dev/null; echo $(( 1 - $? ))'
```

Even this use of `grep` is unnecessary, as `bash` can pattern match for you:

```
const PNAME = '[[ "$( ps -Acxo comm )" =~ processname ]]; echo $(( 1 - $? ))'
```

---

But, putting that to one side, I wouldn't get a shell script to do this unless I were writing a shell script.  JXA is very capable of enumerating processes:

```js
sys = Application('com.apple.SystemEvents');

sys.processes.name();
```

Then, to determine whether a specific named process, e.g. *TextEdit*, is running:

```js
sys.processes['TextEdit'].exists();
```

which will return `true` or `false` accordingly.